# XCode - Debug configuration removes all GCC 4.2 settings

Tags: xcode, configuration, gcc, debugging, release

I have a project that I've just finished painstakingly rebuilding because duplicating a target would cause it to fail (the copy would fail to find its info.plist file no matter what you set in the build settings).

Anyway, now that I've rebuilt the project I've encountered another problem:

If I'm in "Release" configuration, I have access to the following GCC 4.2 sections in the build settings:

- GCC 4.2 - Code Generation
- GCC 4.2 - Language
- GCC 4.2 - Preprocessing
- GCC 4.2 - Warnings

If I switch the configuration over to "Debug", all of those sections disappear.  I can toggle their visibility by switching between "Debug" and "Release".  Quitting and restarting XCode doesn't help.

Is there some other setting I need to have in order to get access to the GCC 4.2 settings in a debug configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuilding the project from scratch a third time solved this issue.

There seem to be some settings in XCode projects that can botch the whole thing.